# ¿Qué utilidad tiene un favicon mayor que 16x16?

Tags: html, icons

Estaba mirando el código fuente de algunas páginas web, y vi que carga un ícono *favicon* varias veces.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
```

El navegador solo muestra un ícono de 16x16 en los marcadores y al lado del título de la pestaña. Entonces, ¿Con qué finalidad se hace esto? ¿y por qué carga más de un *favicon*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La especificación HTML5 actual recomienda el uso de diferentes tamaños para el atributo `favicon`, con la finalidad de que cada agente, o navegador, decida qué tamaño usar para desplegar el contenido del ícono.

Un extracto de la sección [4.2.4 de la especificación HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element):

> El atributo `size` establece el tamaño de los iconos para medios visuales. Este valor, si está presente, es meramente informativo. Los navegadores pueden usar este valor para decidir cuál o cuáles íconos usar si hay múltiples íconos disponibles. Si se especifica, el atributo debe tener un valor tal que sea un conjunto no ordenado de 'tokens' únicos separados por espacio, los cuales son caracteres ASCII que no se distinguen de mayúsculas o minúsculas. Además, cada valor puede ser tanto una cadena ASCII que no distingue de mayúsculas o minúsculas que coincida con el string "any", o un valor que consista de 2 enteros positivos válidos, que no empiecen con un carácter U+0030 DÍGITO CERO (0) y que estén separados por un carácter U+0078 LETRA MINÚSCULA x o U+0058 LETRA MAYÚSCULA X. El atributo no debe ser usado en elementos `link` que no contengan un atributo `rel` que especifique la palabra clave `icon` o la palabra clave `apple-touch-icon`.

(Traducción propia)

Pienso que muchos desarrolladores siguen las pautas de la especificación como una forma de implementar un estándar.

También puedes leer esta información de [Favicon - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon):

> La actual especificación HTML5 recomienda especificar múltiples tamaños para los íconos, usando los atributos `rel="icon" size="lista separada por espacio de dimensiones de iconos"` dentro de una etiqueta `link`. Multiples formatos de íconos, incluyendo formatos contenedores tales como los archivos `.ico` de Microsoft y los archivos `.icns` de Macintosh, así como los Gráficos de Vector Escalabe (SVG) pueden proveerse incluyendo el tipo de contenido en el atributo `type="file content-type"` dentro de la etiqueta `<link>`.

(Traducción propia)

Además, la inmensa cantidad de dispositivos móviles, con su propia implementación de HTML5, hacen posible y hasta necesario iconos de tamaño superior a 16x16, para ser desplegados correctamente en pantallas de alta definición, como las del iPhone o algunas pantallas de dispositivos Android.